# Pure functions in C++11

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

Can one in C++11 somehow in `gcc` mark a function (not a class method) as `const` telling that it is **pure** and does not use the global memory but only its arguments?

I've tried `gcc`'s `__attribute__((const))` and it is **precisely** what I want. But it does not produce any compile time error when the global memory is touched in the function.

**Edit 1**

**Please be careful**. I mean pure functions. **Not constant functions**. GCC's attribute is a little bit confusing. Pure functions only use their arguments.

Comment: nor sure what you mean, but have you tried `constexpr`

Comment: That's NOT it. I mean pure not constant. GCC's attributes are a little bit confusingly named.

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your question, because you have the right attribute. That it doesn't produce the warning you want is a different matter -- at least when taking your question at face value.

Comment: @LucDanton Yes, formally you're absolutely right. But it surprised me that it does not produce any warning nor compile error. And I'd like to know if there is any way how to check it in compile time.

Comment: Im getting interested. Can you please explain how you did this normally, NOT in C++11?

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs I don't know if C++ is able to do that in any version. It's something that is normal and natural in the functional world on the other hand.

Comment: Well, interesting. In this case, I think some others from the functional world could help with this problem, if you are not satisfied with sftrabbit's answer. This last comment of yours was much more enlightening for me than the actual text in the question. You might want to include this info there, along with a tag of your favourite functional programming tags, with explanation...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for `constexpr`? This tells the compiler that the function may be evaluated at compile time. A `constexpr` function must have literal return and parameter types and the body can only contain static asserts, typedefs, using declarations and directives and one return statement. A `constexpr` function may be called in a constant expression.

```
constexpr int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

int x[add(3, 6)];
```

---

Having looked at the meaning of `__atribute__((const))`, the answer is no, you cannot do this with standard C++. Using `constexpr` will achieve the same effect, but only on a much more limited set of functions. There is nothing stopping a compiler from making these optimizations on its own, however, as long as the compiled program behaves the same way (the as-if rule).

Comment: Thank you. Attribute `constexpr` is almost useless. Maybe let's wait a little bit more. Maybe some other `gcc`-specific attribute could help.

Comment: [clang *does* detect and reject modifications](http://goo.gl/QFpk6F) to globals in a `constexpr` function.  gcc 5.3, and gcc6-snapshot just compile the function as written.  IDK how fully clang enforces [constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr), or if you can sneak some violations past it.  Note that C++14 changes the constexpr rules: C++14 has a blacklist of disallowed things, rather than a restrictive whitelist.

Comment: constexpr functions are NOT pure

Comment: ... and pure functions are not necessarily constexpr. This is just a wrong answer

Answer (score 4):

Because it has been mentioned a lot here, lets forget about Meta programming for now,  which is pure functional anyway and off topic. **However, a constexpr function *foo* can be called with non constexpr arguments and in this context *foo* is actually a pure function evaluated at runtime** (I am ignoring global variables here). But you can write many pure functions that you cannot make constexpr, this includes any function throwing exceptions for example.

Second I assume the OP means *marking pure* as an assertion for the compiler to check. GCC's *pure* attribute is the opposite, a way for the coder to help the compiler.

While the answer to the OP's question is NO, it is very interesting to read about the history of attempts to introduce a pure keyword (or *impure* and let *pure* be the default).

The d-lang community quickly figured out that the meaning of "pure" is not clear. Logging should not make a function impure. Mutable variables that do not escape the function call should be allowed in pure functions. Equal return values having different addresses should not be considered impure. But D goes even further than that in stretching purity.

So the d-lang community introduced the term "weakly pure" and "strongly pure". But later disputes showed that weak and strong is not black and white and there are grey zones. see [purity in D](http://klickverbot.at/blog/2012/05/purity-in-d/)

Rust introduced the "pure" keyword early on; and they dropped it because of its complexity. see [purity in Rust](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/rust-dev/2013-April/003926.html).

Among the great benefits of a "pure" keyword there is an ugly consequence though. A templated function can be pure or not depending on its type parameters. This can explode the number of template instantiations. Those instantiations may only need to exist temporarily in the compiler and not get into the executable but they can still explode compile times.

A syntax highlighting editor could be of some help here without modifying the language. Optimizing C++ compilers do actually reason about the pureness of a function, they just do not guarantee catching all cases.

I find it sad that this feature seems to have low priority. It makes reasoning about code so much easier. I would even argue that it would improve software design by the way it incentivizing programmers to think differently.

Answer (score 2):

using just standard C++11:

```
namespace g{ int x; }

constexpr int foo()
{
    //return g::x = 42;  Nah, not constant
    return 42;      // OK
}

int main()
{}
```

---

here's another example:

```
constexpr int foo( int blah = 0 )
{
    return blah + 42;      // OK
}

int main( int argc, char** )
{
    int bah[foo(2)];            // Very constant.
    int const troll = foo( argc );  // Very non-constant.
}
```

---

The meaning of GCC's `__attribute__( const )` is documented in the [GNU compiler docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bconst_007d-function-attribute-2507) as …

> Many functions do not examine any values except their arguments, and have no effects except the return value. Basically this is just slightly more strict class than the `pure` attribute below, since function is not allowed to read global memory.

One may take that to mean that the function result should only depend on the arguments, and that the function should have no side effects.

This allows a more general class of functions than C++11 `constexpr`, which makes the function `inline`, restricts arguments and function result to *literal types*, and restricts the "active" statements of the function body to a single `return` statement, where (C++11 §7.1.5/3)

> — every constructor call and implicit conversion used in initializing the return value (6.6.3, 8.5) shall be one of those allowed in a constant expression (5.19)

As an example, it is difficult (I would think not impossible, but difficult) to make a `constexpr` `sin` function.

But the purity of the result matters only to two parties:

- When known to be pure, the compiler can elide calls with known results.
  This is mostly an optimization of macro-generated code. Replace macros with `inline` functions to avoid silly generation of identical sub-expressions.
- When known to be pure, a programmer can remove a call entirely.
  This is just a matter of proper *documentation*. :-)

So instead of looking for a way to express the purity of e.g. `sin` in the language, I suggest just avoid code generation via macros, and document pure functions as such.

And use `constexpr` for the functions where it's practically possible (unfortunately, as of Dec. 2012 the latest Visual C++ compiler doesn't yet support `constexpr`).

---

There is a previous SO question about [the relationship between *pure* and `constexpr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462388/relation-betwean-constexpr-and-pure-functions). Mainly, every `constexpr` function is *pure*, but not vice versa.

Comment: No no no, I mean pure functions, not constant functions.

Comment: My problem? The question was intended to those people who know the meaning of `pure` and the GCC's attributes.

Comment: But sorry, if it was not clear. But you can always remove your answer. The downvote has been removed as well.

Comment: @Martin: from your (vague) description of "pure" it looks as if `constexpr` is what you're looking for.

Comment: It's better to ask first and look at what `__attribute__((const))` means.

Comment: Cheers: If I wanted to troll, I'd say that I expected that the people in Microsoft know what does "pure function" mean ;-) No offense.

Comment: No offense but GCC sucks at naming attributes. In particular the 'pure' attribute is completely misnamed.